# Why the Main function accepts (string [] args)?

Tags: c#, function, program-entry-point

I mean that I don't quite understand why such parameters as string [] and what should be passed into them, if Main is the entry point to the program.

for example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
         int number1 = 5;
        ChanfeVal(number1);
        System.Console.WriteLine(number1); 
    }
```

Comment: Do you know what a command line is?

Answer (score 0):

That is an array of strings, and it will contain any command line arguments you added when calling the program from the command line. For example, if you open your terminal and run "myprogram.exe testme" then "testme" will be in args[1] and "myprogram.exe" will be in args[0].

As far as "what parameters", that is up to you. If your program doesn't do anything with command line arguments, then you don't need to pass anything.